# Event listener is not triggered when using with drop-down?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events

I am trying to **trigger the event listener whenever the user selects anything from the dropdown but it is not working**, I am using the select2 plugin for the dropdown.

I am trying to send some values through ajax whenever the user selects from the dropdown, but unfortunately, it is not triggering.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".select2").select2();

});

const select = document.querySelector('#Country');
const resultsContainer = document.querySelector('#results');
let currentIndex = 0;

select.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  const countryId = event.target.value;
  console.log(countryId);
  console.log("hi");
   //ajax call here!
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select class="select2 form-control" name="Country" id="Country" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="Country" selected>---Select Country---</option>
    <option value="Ägypten">Ägypten (Egypt)</option>
    <option value="Argentinien">Argentinien (Argentinia)</option>
    <option value="Äthiopien">Äthiopien (Ethiopia)</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: The drop-down you see on the view is not the one you've created in the markup. Use the event model of [Select2](https://select2.org/) library.

Comment: I have checked and the basic usage is the same as I wrote see [here](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage), it is just that whenever the user selects anything it should triggered or  console the value, you have any suggestions?

Comment: I love when people start arguing ... Please right-click on the drop-down, select "Inspect element" from the opened menu. You can see there's a totally different elements shown, it's not a select element at all.

Comment: I apologize if my statement seems rude, see I have checked as you suggested in the inspect element it seems the same [inspect](https://imgur.com/a/edRJxvR)

Comment: I don't know how you've created that screenshot, most likely the select2 element is not created at that point. Anyway, put everything in `document.ready`, store a reference to the newly-created select2 object into a variable, and use jQuery `on` to attach the change event to that __select2 object__ (not to your original `<select>` element), that way your code will work.

Comment: could you please show me any reference or pseudo code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k96j0b3c/